# Log4j timebasedrolling policy not working for me

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, log4j, rollingfileappender

I created a spring boot rest api and planning to use log4j for logging. I am able to log using dailyrollingfileappender but I dont like the format of the filename [app.log.date] so I tried using log4j extras. I'm having problems I have an error when I start tomcat

"log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [TimeBasedRollingPolicy].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TimeBasedRollingPolicy"

Here's my pom.xml log4j dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here's my log4j properties file (Currently modifying auditLogger)

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.logger.auditLogger = INFO, auditLogger

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.generalLogger=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.generalLogger.File=C:\\logs\\sms-syslog.log
log4j.appender.generalLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.generalLogger.DatePattern='_'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.generalLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.category.generalLogger=INFO, generalLogger
log4j.additivity.generalLogger=false

log4j.appender.auditLogger=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.auditLogger.rollingPolicy=TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.auditLogger.File=C:\\logs\\sms-audit.log
log4j.appender.auditLogger.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=C:\\logs\\sms-audit-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
log4j.appender.auditLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.auditLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p: %m%n
log4j.additivity.auditLogger=false
```

Here's my call for auditlogger in code

```
private static final Logger auditLogger = Logger.getLogger("auditLogger");
```

Please help. I am quite lost Thank you!

Comment: Do we need FQN for `rolling policy`? i.e `org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy` ??

Comment: Thank you! you're a God!

Comment: Please mark your own answer as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was provided by Pete.

The properties file was fine, I just needed the FQN.

```
log4j.appender.auditLogger.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
```

Answer (score 0):

use below dependency for `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

refer below link for reference: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/logback/logback-rollingfileappender-example/

Comment: So i wont use log4j extras anymore?